# How to combine 2 tables in R with same date range and Calculate Correlation?

Tags: r

I am new to R programming.

I have to calculate Correlation between 2 stocks.

I have downloaded data from yahoo using below code.

```
library(quantmod)  
library(Quandl)  
getSymbols("NMDC.NS", src="yahoo")  
getSymbols("IDFC.NS", src="yahoo")
```

both the table has different date range in table. I would like to calculate correlation between 2 stocks, for that i need close prices with same date range in one separate table.

NMDC data starts from 2008-03-03, IDFC data starts from 2007-01-02.

I need to make sure my data doesn't contain any "NA".
Can anyone help me to combine both table and calculate correlation between both stocks.

Comment: Just `merge` them by date and use `cor` (correlation) function with option `use = "p"` (will take care of `NA`)

Answer (score 0):

The `quantmod` library depends on the `xts` which is need to merge the `xts`-objects you obtain by using the `getSymbols` functions, therefore it is already loaded. You can use the `merge.xts` function as follows:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("NMDC.NS", src="yahoo")
getSymbols("IDFC.NS", src="yahoo")
mds <- merge.xts(NMDC.NS, IDFC.NS, join = "inner")
with(mds, cor(NMDC.NS.Adjusted, IDFC.NS.Adjusted, use = "pairwise"))
```

The option `use = pairwise` tells the `cor` function to use pairwise complete observations, so that if any value is missing in one time series, this value and the corresponding one from the other time series are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will apply the same and confirm soon.

Comment: It didn't worked. I am getting all columns when i view mds object.

Comment: And why would this be a problem? If you want to keep only a subset of columns just do `mds[,c("name_of_a_column","name_of_other_column")]`. However in your question you wanted to get the correlation between two stocks and this is exactly what my answer does, you did not specify (nor is it necessary) that you wanted to keep only certain columns.